# bartlett.test fail with formula col1~col2+col3

Tags: r, variance

I wish to perform a `bartlett.test` with multiple independent grouping variables. However, an error is generated.

Here is some data:

```
d=read.table(text='
1 w e
2 w e
3 w r
3 e r
4 e r
5 e e
4 w r
6 e e')
```

When I test the homogeneity of variance with one grouping variable only using formula V1 ~ V2, everything is perfect:

```
bartlett.test(V1 ~ V2, data = d)

    Bartlett test of homogeneity of variances

data:  V1 by V2
Bartlett's K-squared = 0, df = 1, p-value = 1
```

But when trying multiple independent variables, results in an error:

```
bartlett.test(V1 ~ V2 + V3, data = d)
Error in bartlett.test.formula(V1 ~ V2 + V3, data = d) : 
  'formula' should be of the form response ~ group
```

And yet I want to test homogeneity of variance with multi-column, that is, test V1 ~ V2 + V3, so any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**This tutorial**](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Statistical_analysis/Homogeneity_of_variance/) suggests that "With multiple independent variables, the `interaction` function must be used to collapse the IV's into a single variable with all combinations of the factors. If it is not used, then the will be the wrong degrees of freedom, and the p-value will be wrong.". Thus,

```
bartlett.test(V1 ~ interaction(V2, V3), data = d)
# Bartlett test of homogeneity of variances
# 
# data:  V1 by interaction(V2, V3)
# Bartlett's K-squared = 0, df = 3, p-value = 1
```

Comment: The same happens for `kruskal.test`.